# Why Orchard cms display error when i try to use modules file?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I've a problem, I've just installed one external module for add some login functionality, but now I must change the login shape. I've just copy the view for the login from the module as soon as installed, but now my project doesn't compile. It doesn't find one model class of the module, that it's use from my .cshtml file. 
I've already tried to solve by adding the reference of the module and also add it namespace into web.config, but all without any success. Can anyone tell me how to solve? I'd must to use the model class of the module inside my cshtml without error.

Thanks.

Comment: In order for people to help you, you need to tell them as much as you can about the errors and the related configuration and code.

Comment: I've installed and enable OpenAuthentication module, and now it was change the standard Logon view adding other functionality. Now I must to modify it by copy the above view into my custom theme and then add other changes, but when I try to import it into the theme I always get the same error: the type or namespace name "OrchardAuthenticathionClientData" could not be found an assembly reference?). I've already set reference for the module and also trie to add it's assembly into web.config but all without success. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've solve the problem by close and re-open Visual Studio and then do a clean and build and at rthe end reboot my pc. 
After that when I had reopen the solution, I had see taht it had found the references building all without problems.

Thank's of all.